# Clean URL in drupal 6.20 with IIS6

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, iis-6

I had uploaded my site to hosting company with configuration as listed below

Mysql 5.1.49,
PHP 5.2.12,
Microsoft-IIS/6.0.

In the drupal report page there is only one error message
"register_globals is enabled. Drupal requires this configuration directive to be disabled. Your site may not be secure when register_globals is enabled. The PHP manual has instructions for how to change configuration settings".

The problem is I cant enable the clean url feature, without this site links are not functioning ! I had tried .htaccess with some combinations which I found from the web but all ends in negative result.

Is this can make right with correct .htaccess setting ? IF so how ? is there any other way to make this correct. My hosting provider will not allow me to edit their server setting !

Please help me in this matter

I had this same site running localy with apache.

---

I had changes the plan to linux, now only a single problem exists. Logo is not showing ? my logo is placed as shows in source code of the page.

```
<a href="/" title="Olives"><img src="/sites/default/files/bluemarine_logo.png" alt="Olives" /></a>
```

when the site is offline its showing but when I enable or login with user its not showing ?
any hep to sort this, will be appreciated.

Comment: .htaccess is how to do this with the Apache web server. IIS uses an entirely different mechanism. (by the way, while Drupal does work well in IIS, it's generally a better fit with an apache server; if you've got the option to do so and it's not too late, it might be worth switching to an Apache based server)

Comment: Yes I found the error !
the image name was "bluemarine_logo.png" in file folder it was "bluemarine_logo.PNG" so just renamed file extension to small letter and it works ! thanx for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Microsoft IIS 6 has no support for URL Rewriting at all.
- IIS 7 has a URL Rewrite Module (which still needs to be downloaded separately).
- IIS 7.5 (Windows 7 & Windows Server 2008 R2) already comes with URL Rewrite Module bundled (v1.x) .. but you still want to update it to the newer v2 separately.

In any case -- IIS7 has it's own format which is not compatible with .htaccess unless some 3rd party tool is used instead (like [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/) for example). But IIS7 **can** convert Apache's mod_rewrite rules into it's own format.

**On Microsoft IIS6** you have to install [Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite v3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) or similar software -- it does support almost all functionality of Apache's mod_rewrite.

Ask your hosting company what URL Rewrite module is installed there. If none -- ask if they can install one for you. If still nothing and Microsoft platform is required -- maybe search for hosting with IIS7 -- it may have URL Rewrite installed and enabled by default.

**EDIT:** *removed "stick to Apache" sentence.*

Comment: Everything is great about this answer except the last sentence which is not very well informed. Microsoft have spent a lot of time with the PHP community making sure that PHP and lots of popular PHP apps such as Drupal run well on IIS6 and 7. I work for a shared web hoster and can vouch for PHP+Drupal et al running just as well on Windows as it does on our Linux platform. This is a huge change from the situation a few years back where I wouldn't allow PHP on Windows at all.

Comment: @Kev I agree with you in general as IIS 7 is my primary deployment platform (I'm using PHP & SQL Server 2005/2008). And it works absolutely fine on our dedicated/VP servers. But for sharing hosting I have quite opposite feelings. I agree -- my last sentence is not perfectly worded -- I should have added "considering your need in URL Rewrite & depending on how busy your site is". Microsoft indeed did a great job in speeding up/supporting PHP (that includes WinCache, PHP Driver for SQL Server etc).

Comment: @Kev: Drupal is happier in a Linux/Apache environment. Tools like Drush have loads of functionality which only works that environment, and are not possible with Windows/IIS. I know the Drupal folk are working on this (and I'm sure the Microsoft folk are too), but the fact remains that for the time being Drupal is best run on Linux/Apache.

Comment: You're right "LazyOne" IIS6 doesn't support rewrite module and my hosting company is not ready to install one. So I changed the plan to linux.

Comment: Now the problem is I am not getting the banner display all that appear below. I had cleared the cache and setting page is corrected to right db, .htaccess RewriteBase / is enabled also in setting Base url is defined as "http://www.mydomain.com"; still no header. 

But if I loged in I will get the banner but Image is showing broken all layout broken. How can I fix this ? Please help me to sort this thing. In status file system path showing error ? I worked in XAMP windows dont know a bit of linux !
thanx for the responses to all.